# Alternate br.read()'s are getting skipped. How to make them visible to the compiler?

Tags: java, input, line, bufferedreader

```
    System.out.println("Q1.HOW DO YOU RECHARGE?");
    System.out.println("A. SPENDING TIME ALONE");
    System.out.println("B. PUBLIC DISCUSSIONS OR PARTIES");
    System.out.println("C. BOTH OF THEM ARE FINE IF I'M IN THE MOOD");
    char choice1 = (char)br.read();//this line gets executed perfectly fine
    if(choice1 == 'A')
    ct+=20;
    else if(choice1 == 'B')
    ct+=10;
    else
    ct+=30;
    System.out.println("Q2.ARE YOU OPEN TO NEW PEOPLE?");
    System.out.println("A. YES OF COURSE");
    System.out.println("B. I DON'T WANT TO TALK TO NEW PEOPLE");
    System.out.println("C. I CAN'T OPEN UP TO NEW PEOPLE UNTIL THEY ARE CLOSE ENOUGH");
    char choice2 = (char)br.read();//this one doesn't
    if(choice2 == 'A')
    ct+=10;
    else if(choice2 == 'B')
    ct+=20;
    else
    ct+=30;
    System.out.println("Q3.WOULD YOU GO FIRST OR LAST FOR A PRESENTATION?");
    System.out.println("A. I GUESS I WOULD GO FIRST ONLY IF I'M VERY CONFIDENT");
    System.out.println("B. OF COURSE FIRST!");
    System.out.println("C. NO. SO THAT I CAN LEARN FROM OTHER'S MISTAKES");
    char choice3 = (char)br.read();//this does
    if(choice3 == 'A')
    ct+=30;
    else if(choice3 == 'B')
    ct+=10;
    else
    ct+=20;
```

and so on till the end all the read's at even positions get ignored though the corresponding questions get printed. Tried doing all sorts of wacky things and now I've lost hope, PLEASE help!

Comment: You're forgetting the newline (enter) characters entered by the user.  `read()` reads only one character, and the next `read()` reads the newline.

Comment: Please format this illegible mess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Jim Garrison said , This is because of forgetting the `newline` *(enter)* characters entered by the user.

To solve the replace

```
(char)br.read();
```

With

```
(char)br.readLine().charAt(0);
```

The charAt(index) function in Java returns the character present at the index position of the concerned String.Here `0 th` position ,ie first character .This will work.

So the modification is :-

```
char choice1 = (char)br.readLine().charAt(0); // Line 5
char choice2 = (char)br.readLine().charAt(0); // Line 16
char choice3 = (char)br.readLine().charAt(0); // Line 27
```